# How to automatically choose a good ylim to read geom_labels in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, tidyverse

Suppose I write the following code with the `diamonds` dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut) %>% 
    summarize(total_value = sum(price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    arrange(total_value) %>% 
    mutate(cut = as_factor(cut)) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(., 1))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = total_value)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = cut)) +
    theme(legend.position = "note") +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_label(aes(label = paste0("$", total_value)), size = 6) +
    labs(title = "Total Value of Diamonds by Cut", y = "USD", x = "") +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1)))
```

which outputs the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, it is impossible to read the last digit(s) of the first category ("Ideal").

So, my question is, I know I can simply write something like `coord_flip(ylim = c(0,80000000)` and this would solve the problem; however, what could I write instead for ggplot2 to automatically know by itself how much space it should provide in `ylim` for people to clearly read the `geom_label()`s without me having to do this manually?

I'm trying to create an automatic Dashboard with multiple plots such as this, but I cannot manually tune every one of those, I need an automatic mechanism and I haven't found anything regarding this on StackOverflow for `geom_label()` specifically.

Thanks.

Comment: `+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.05, 0, 0.1, 0))` might help. It set's the upper expansion double the size it currently is. Increase the `0.1` as needed.

Comment: Well, adding labels to every bar kind of defeats the whole purpose of having an x-axis. If you need everyone to see exact amounts, maybe just show a table rather than a bar plot.  Or if you really need labels, list put the all at the left. Is there really a reason they need to be to the left of the bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of positioning your `label` at the the bar, you could move it closer to the middle and adjust position with `vjust` so it won't spill out of the plot set to include the bars.

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarize(total_value = sum(price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(total_value) %>% 
  mutate(cut = as_factor(cut)) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(., 1))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = total_value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = cut)) +
  theme(legend.position = "note") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_label(aes(label = paste0("$", total_value), y = total_value/2), size = 6, hjust = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "Total Value of Diamonds by Cut", y = "USD", x = "") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1)))
```

That gives:

[image: plot without clipped labels]

Comment: This is a sound solution. Also, thanks to @teunbrand for mentioning the use of `+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.05, 0, 0.1, 0))` which is also very helpful.